# Excel VBA script index error

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for half an hour for a fix now. I got 3 possible values (low,mid and high), and I want d to be a value from one through three. I get an error when I run the script.

```
Sub GetStructure()

Dim d As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim o As Integer
Dim o2 As Integer

  i = Worksheets("Control").Cells(14, 2).Value
  d = Worksheets("Control").Cells(9, 2).Value

  If d = "High" Then
  d = 3
  End If

  If d = "Mid" Then
  d = 2
  End If

  If d = "Low" Then
  d = 1

  End If
```

Comment: You are trying to put a string in an integer variable. Change it to a range and  `set d = Worksheets("Control").Cells(9, 2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define `Dim d As Integer`

An Integer is a number. If you write `If d = "High"` you compare an Integer with a String

So define another Variable `Dim v As String` then you can assign `v = Worksheets("Control").Cells(9, 2).Value` and check it with `If v = "High" Then` for all cases.